# Show next/previous post title without link

Tags: php, wordpress

This seems like something that should be simple, but I can't figure out how to fetch the next and previous post titles in WordPress without links.

On the codex, [`next_post_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link) and [`previous_post_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post_link) don't seem to have parameters to allow you to get the title without it's link, and I can't find any workarounds online.

Seems like this should be a common thing. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured out something using `get_adjacent_post`. Not sure if this is the right method but it works.

```
<?php 
$prev_post = get_adjacent_post('', '', true);
$next_post = get_adjacent_post('', '', false);
?>
<p><?php echo $prev_post->post_title; ?></p>
<p><?php echo $next_post->post_title; ?></p>
```